# Why does nunique overwrite the grouping column in pandas

Tags: pandas

Here is a dramatically simplified version of my data

```
+---+---------+-----------+
|   | user_id | module_id |
+---+---------+-----------+
| 0 |       1 |         1 |
| 1 |       1 |         2 |
| 2 |       1 |         3 |
| 3 |       2 |         1 |
| 4 |       2 |         1 |
| 5 |       2 |         2 |
+---+---------+-----------+
```

```python
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'module_id':[1,2,3,1,1,2]})
```

If I group this on user_id and then aggregate using sum I get the expected result:

```python
df.groupby('user_id', as_index=False).sum()
```

```
+---+---------+-----------+
|   | user_id | module_id |
+---+---------+-----------+
| 0 |       1 |         6 |
| 1 |       2 |         4 |
+---+---------+-----------+
```

However, if I instead aggregate using nunique the grouping column is also aggregated:

```python
df.groupby('user_id', as_index=False).nunique()
```

```
+---+---------+-----------+
|   | user_id | module_id |
+---+---------+-----------+
| 0 |       1 |         3 |
| 1 |       1 |         2 |
+---+---------+-----------+
```

Why is changing my aggregation function from `sum` to `nunique` overwriting my groupby column user_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the way of `nunqiue` , since you did not mentioned which columns to apply the function , so it will apply to each column in dfs , which will return the 1 for `groupby` id

```
df.groupby('user_id')['module_id'].nunique().reset_index()
Out[521]: 
   user_id  module_id
0        1          3
1        2          2
```

Comment: In my real data there are lots of columns I want to apply nunique to and a few I don't, is there an easy way to tell nunique which ones to skip?

Comment: @dumbledad you may need to know which column you want to apply the function , then just slice it

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide column name

```
df.groupby('user_id')[['module_id']].nunique().reset_index()
```

```
  user_id   module_id
0   1         3
1   2         2
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html

This tells the exact use of nunique(), for your case it will return the number of unique elements in the group fro each column.